# Is my question about 4e encounter tables too broad or easy?

Tags: discussion

As we continue to work out these boundaries, I'm curious about the opinions on this question.  If people have made a set of tables, they are presumably locatable on google, but I have been unable to do so.  The discussion seems to be about how hard something must be to find before it is a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a valid question. I've been wishing I had an answer to it, cause I could use the same.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if that's a general need--maybe I'll take a stab at a set and ask for some feedback.